# R - Applying formula to all values in column

Tags: r, foreach, plyr

I have a data frame `b1`:

[image: df]

And these numeric vectors:

```
R = 100000  
Sfi = as.numeric(c(0:99))
```

I'd like to create another column in the data frame `b1` with values derived from the formula

```
q = prod((R - Ac - Sfi) / (R - Sfi))
```

When I plug values from `Ac` directly into the equation, I get a reasonable answer. However, I have been very unsuccessful in applying it to the data frame. I have a large number of similar data frames, so would like an efficient way to do these calculations.

I have tried `adply`, but get the same result for all values of `Ac`:

```
adply(b1,1,function(x){  
     q=prod((R-b1$Ac-Sfi)/(R-Sfi))  
     data.frame(Qipg=q)  
     })
```

[image: adply]

or

```
 adply(b1,1,function(x){  
     q=prod((R-Ac-Sfi)/(R-Sfi))  
     data.frame(Qipg=q)  
     })
```

Here I get this error:

> ```
> Error in .fun(piece, ...) : object 'Ac' not found
> ```

I have also tried the `foreach` function:

```
foreach(i = b1$Ac, Sfi = c(0:99)) %do% (prod(R - i - Sfi) / (R - Sfi))
```

but get the same numerical results regardless of what numbers I plug into `Sfi` -- `c(0:99)`, `c(0:500)`, whatever. I also get same result whether I include the `sum`, `prod`, or no function along with `(R - i - Sfi) / (R - Sfi)`.

Any ideas on what I ought to be doing to get the results (column) that I am looking for?

Comment: Since `Ac` is in a data.frame, you need to reference it with `$`-notation: `prod((R - b1$Ac - Sfi) / (R - Sfi))`. If you want to run that formula across a range of values, use `sapply`: `b1$q <- sapply(b1$Ac, function(x){prod((R - x - Sfi) / (R - Sfi))})`

Comment: This worked! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `apply` function to loop down all rows and calculate your equation. You should first create a one-variable data frame with just the values of `Ac` to loop down.

```
Ac <- data.frame(b1$Ac)
b1$q <- apply(Ac, 1, function(x) prod((R-x-Sfi)/(R-Sfi)))
```

Comment: You need to edit with some text explaining your answer; code-only answers are discouraged on SO.